# How to add a combo box on a navigation forma as a filter

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am fairly new to Access.

I have two forms. I put these two forms into a navigation form with each form on a tab. now I want to have a combo box on the navigation form that will serve as a filter for both of the two forms inside the navigation form. the combo box will have the values coming from a field in another table. How do I do this. Thank you, and sorry I am fairly new to this.

[image: Sample image is shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some VBA code to activate a filter on your subform(s). In my example I added a clickevent for an OK-button to apply the filter, but you could also make it an afterupdate event on your combobox:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
If IsNull(Me.cmbFilter) Then
   Me.subfrmName1.Form.Filter = ""
   Me.subfrmName2.Form.Filter = ""
   Me.subfrmName1.Form.FilterOn = False
   Me.subfrmName2.Form.FilterOn = False
Else
  Me.subfrmName1.Form.Filter = "[State]='" & Me.cmbFilter.Value & "'"
  Me.subfrmName2.Form.Filter = "[State]='" & Me.cmbFilter.Value & "'"
  Me.subfrmName1.Form.FilterOn = True
  Me.subfrmName2.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub
```